# How to get \ hfill in double dollar environment

Tags: spacing

Can anyone tell me how to get \hfill like spacing in double dollar environment? Please find the image to know what exactly I am asking for.[image]

Comment: Are ou compiling i plain TeX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need not to use `\hfil` TeX primitive but `\eqno` TeX primitive:

```
\def\n||#1||{\mathopen{\Vert}#1\mathclose{\Vert}}

\noindent{\bf Definition.} A normed linear space $A, \n||.||$ over $C$ is said
be a {\it normed algebra}, if $A$ is an algebra and
$$
  \n||xy|| \le \n||x|| \n||y|| \eqno (x, y \in A)
$$

\bye
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are two possible LaTeX-based solutions. The first solution uses the `\tag*` directive to place `(x,y\in A).` at the right-hand edge. A possible downside of this notation is that `(x,y\in A).` might be misinterpreted as some kind of equation "number". The second solution therefore places this element closer to the other material of the displayed equation.

[image]

Note the creation of a "high-level" macro named `\alg` to denote algebras. In the definition, `\alg` is set to use `\mathcal`; depending on your preferences and the notational conventions you may need to satisfy, other possible choices are `\mathscr`, `\mathfrak`, and `\mathsf`. (Writing `$A$` may not be enough to create a sufficient visual distinction for uppercase letters that are supposed to denote algebras.)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\alg}[1]{\mathcal{#1}} % or: \mathsf, \mathfrak, \mathscr
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition} % upright (non-italic) text in body of env.
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{defn}{1}

%% first solution
\begin{defn}
A normed linear space $(\alg{A},\norm{\cdot})$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is said
to be a \emph{normed algebra} if $\alg{A}$ is an algebra and
\[
\norm{xy} \le \norm{x}\norm{y} \tag*{($x,y\in\alg{A}$).}
\]
\end{defn}

\refstepcounter{section} % optional

%% second solution
\begin{defn}
A normed linear space $(\alg{A},\norm{\cdot})$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is said
to be a \emph{normed algebra} if $\alg{A}$ is an algebra and
\[
\norm{xy} \le \norm{x}\norm{y} \quad \forall\ x,y\in\alg{A}\,.
\]
\end{defn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In my opinion one should type `... if $A$ is an algebra and, for all $x,y\in A$,\[\norm{xy}\le\norm{x}\norm{y}.\]`. The “x,y in A” in parentheses at the right margin means nothing and is at least distracting. I know it's frequently seen like in the picture, but it doesn't make it better.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for this. It was precisely because I believed that "(x,y in A)" at the right-hand margin verges on being misleading or distracting that I came up with the second solution shown above. I fully agree that placing "x,y in A" *before" the display-equation part is even better than what I wrote...

Answer (score 1):

Using `\tag*{}` in a right-numbered environment is a "hack" that hijacks the equation numbering mechanism (works fine if all equations are numbered on the right).

For a more general solution, working for displayed equations in LaTeX is to **use the `flalign` environment**, which also works with left-numbered equations:

[image]

Columns are separated with `&` as usual and the first column is aligned to the very left, the last column to the very right (same effect as using `\hfill`).

Here is the code for the above picture

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{definition}[equation]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\section{Definitions}

\begin{definition}
A normed linear space $(A, \lVert {\cdot} \rVert)$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is said
to be a \emph{normed algebra} if $A$ is an algebra and
\begin{flalign*}
&& \lVert xy \rVert \leq \lVert x \rVert \lVert y \rVert && (x, y \in A).
\end{flalign*}
\end{definition}

You can also remove the asterisk to get a numbered equation.

\begin{definition}
A normed linear space $(A, \lVert {\cdot} \rVert)$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is said
to be a \emph{normed algebra} if $A$ is an algebra and
\begin{flalign}
\label{normedalgebra}
&& \lVert xy \rVert \leq \lVert x \rVert \lVert y \rVert && (x, y \in A).
\end{flalign}
\end{definition}

The condition (\ref{normedalgebra}) is called XYZ.

\end{document}
```